# 複数端末からのダウンロード速度は分割されるものなのでしょうか？

Tags: network

自宅のインターネット環境におけるネットワークスピードについてご指南頂けませんでしょうか？

環境
回線：1Gbps
端末：Windows10 1台　プリンタ1台
ルータ：1台
HUB：１台

現在このような環境下においてインターネットを利用しております。
大きなファイルをダウンロードするときのスピードは100MB/sです。

この時に、Windows10 の端末をもう一台追加して同じように大きなファイルを同時にダウンロードするとそれぞれスピードは半分（50MB/s）になってしまうのでしょうか？

ネットワークの仕組みを理解していないのですが、利用する端末が増えれば増えるほど反比例的にスピードは遅くなるものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1Gbps は 1G bit/sec = 1000M bit/sec (回線上のビット数＝ペイロード＋オーバヘッド）
100MB/s は (100M*8bit)/sec = 800M bit/sec (ペイロードのみ)

なわけで、与えられた帯域を使い切っていますから、２台で同じようにダウンロードをするなら１台あたりは 50MB/s になるものと思われます。３台なら 33MB/s 。

ペイロードとオーバーヘッドについてわからなかったら別途質問立ててください。

Comment: 承知いたしました！具体的な説明ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

台数が増えれば1台あたりのスループットが低下するのはほぼ間違いありませんが、1台で100MB/sだったら2台で50MB/sずつ、にはまずなりません。

1台での通信ではオーバーヘッドにより帯域を使い切れなかったものが、2台で通信することでより多くの帯域を使用するようになるかもしれません。逆に、通信量が増えることで経路のどこかでバッファがあふれるなどして実効スループットが1台の時より下がるかもしれません

また、一般的に通信は先に届いたものから順に処理されるだけなので、どのようにデータが流れるかは状況次第で、結果的に帯域をどのように分け合うかは変化します。